# Converting simple column of decimal numbers into numeric values?

Tags: r, numeric

I've merged two datasets in R of both numeric and categorical variables. A column of data, constant GDP is represented as numbers (ex: 478.3044, 568.1392). However, R interprets this column as a factor:

```
is.numeric(data$GDP)
#[1] FALSE
```

I have attempted to convert to numerical values with `as.numeric(data$GDP)` but R still determines the column to be categorical.

Is there any way to convert this data within the data frame?

Comment: `data$GDP <- as.numeric(as.character(data$GDP))`

Comment: How did you merge the two datasets together? You may be able to explicitly state not to treat numerics as factors there.

Comment: @setty, I merged with: total <- merge(Dataset1, Dataset2, by=c("variable1","variable2"))

Comment: @RonakShah, the code worked! Thank you very much.